# How to remediate Microsoft typeinfo.name() memory leaks?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, memory-leaks, typeinfo

Microsoft has a decades old bug when using its leak check gear in debug builds. The leak is reported from the allocation made by the runtime library when using C++ type information, like `typeinfo.name()`. Also see [Memory leaks reported by debug CRT inside typeinfo.name()](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=106937) on Microsoft Connect.

We've been getting error reports and user list discussions because of the leaks for about the same amount of time. The Microsoft bug could also mask real leaks from user programs. The latter point is especially worrisome to me because we may not tending to real problems because of the masking.

I'd like to try to squash the leaks due to use of `typeid(T)` and `typeinfo.name()`. My question is, how can we work around Microsoft's bug? Is there a work around available?

Comment: Don't use `typeinfo.name()`?

Comment: Thanks Sam. I can't find any information on [licensing the source code](http://www.google.com/search?q=license+microsoft+c%2B%2B+runtime+source+code). Do you have a link? Also, how does the fix work in this case? Are all users expected to license? Or do we license and distribute with side-by-side linking with `.local` DLL redirection? The latter does not seem like a viable option, but I want to ensure I understand the process.

Comment: Suggestion: revisit all the places you are using `typeinfo.name()` and replace the calls with something directing the call to some Meyer's singleton functions or templates or something - at least, there will be a limited amount of 'leaking' by static variables.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Its not that easy for us. We basically have serialization code that calls `typeid(T)`, and does things like `if (valueType == typeid(int))`. Its limited to two or three source files, but its called frequently with different types. If I am parsing the suggestion correctly, we will move the leak into the Singleton.

Comment: @jww  "If I am parsing the suggestion correctly, we will move the leak into the Singleton. " Yes, that was my suggestion. You asked for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks again Adrian. We were kind of hoping to squash all of them. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @jww "We were kind of hoping to squash all of them." Since it doesn't seem possible, the next best thing would be to isolate/tag them. Being inside some templated classes, one can hope that the 'mem leaking' report will use the class names (or at least the source file where the allocation happened) - you can subsequently use this information to filter them out from the 'all leaked memory reports'.

Answer (score 1):

On the line of my suggestion in the Q's comments.

For `if (valueType == typeid(int))` you can use the [`type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) (at least since C++11)

---

For `type_info.name()` leaking memory:

Since totally eliminating the leak doesn't seem possible, the next best thing would be reduce their number (to only one leaked per type interrogation) and, secondary, to tag them for reporting purposes. 
Being inside some templated classes, one can hope that the 'mem leaking' report will use the class names (or at least the source file where the allocation happened) - you can subsequently use this information to filter them out from the 'all leaked memory' reports.

So instead of using `typeid(<typename>)`, you use something like:

"file typeid_name_workaround.hpp"

```
template <typename T> struct get_type_name {
  static const char* name() const {
    static const char* ret=typeid(T).name();
    return ret;
  }
};
```

Other `.cpp/.hpp` file

```
#include "typeid_name_workaround.hpp"

struct dummy {
};

int main() {
  // instead of typeid(dummy).name() you use
  get_type_name<dummy>::name();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. That did not work well. The number of reported memory leaks increased from 32 to 40. I guess the temporaries made matters worse. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Oh, well, what can I say? I'd live with only 32 of 'not-even-proper leaks' (their number doesn't increase over time). Yes, I can see them called leaks, as you can do nothing to free the memory before exiting the program; but be aware that [not everyone agrees the memory has to be freed before exiting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120105-00/?p=8683) (... a MSDN blog entry, does it surprise you? I reckon this should tell you to *not* hold  your breath until a fix for that bug). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Yeah, I've seen the "its not a leak" position before. I think its fine as long as it does not affect others or test results. But in this case, it affects non-MS code by interfering with testing and by hiding leaks, so its probably a security bug. Also, if the code is used in a library (like a DLL), the memory leak could grow unbounded when called from managed languages like Java and .Net. Java and .Net will load and unload the DLL multiple times.