# Memory leak in Crypto++ RSAES class

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, memory-leaks, crypto++

I'm trying to learn how to use [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/) classes. My goal is to generate public and private keys for RSA encryption and then do basic encryption and decryption of a plaintext.

So I'm taking their example [from here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Encryption_Schemes) -- "*RSA Encryption Scheme (OAEP and SHA) using Filters*", slightly modified for readability:

This parts works OK:

```
CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

//Generate Parameters
CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction params;
params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 3072);

//Create Keys
CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey privateKey(params);
CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey publicKey(params);

std::string plain="Hello world!", cipher, recovered;

//Encryption
CryptoPP::RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(publicKey);
```

But then when I call this block:

```
CryptoPP::StringSink* pSS = new CryptoPP::StringSink( cipher );
CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter* pEF = new CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter( rng, e, pSS);

CryptoPP::StringSource ss1( plain, true, pEF);
```

It causes the memory leak(s). I get the following in the `Visual Studio` output window:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{24781} normal block at 0x029BCFF8, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <class CryptoPP::> 63 6C 61 73 73 20 43 72 79 70 74 6F 50 50 3A 3A 
{24780} normal block at 0x029BCFB0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <        > F8 CF 9B 02 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

OK, so I did the most obvious thing and added these:

```
delete pEF;
delete pSS;
```

but it caused an unhandled exception, so I assumed that one of the destructors in Crypto++ classes took care of deleting some of those objects.

So the question is -- where is this leak coming from?

I tried stepping into `StringSink`, `PK_EncryptorFilter` and `StringSource` with a Visual Studio debugger to see what's going on, but the code is quite convoluted to figure it out right away.

Any idea how to fix those memory leaks?

Comment: Surely you can you trim your leak down to a [mcve]

Comment: @jww: I was able to answer my second question myself. See the edit in my OP.

Comment: @jww: Hey! I just posted a solution to that 2nd problem and you removed it. WTF?

Comment: Also see [Windows Debug build memory leaks cleared](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/32OQVPdflZk). The library moved to static initialization from dynamic initialization to avoid problems on Microsoft platforms. Its a "best effort" to use static initialization, if available. Otherwise, things fall back to dynamic initialization. Here, "static initialization" means getting library objects into the CRT static initialization list that runs constructor functions and calls global object ctors (and not a static C++ object).

Comment: @jww: OK. That's good news. Does it mean though that there's a new version of CryptoCPP library that I can download that includes that fix?

Comment: If you want the updated code, then you have to work from Master. The next release is Crypto++ 6.0, but its not ready yet because we still need to add curve25519. Its OK to work from Master because its mostly stable. It gets an occasional break, but we usually catch them during testing before users experience pain.

Comment: @jww: That's OK, I can wait. Can you estimate how soon when the updated code will be released in 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

> It causes the memory leak(s). I get the following in the Visual Studio
>   output window:
>
> ```
> Detected memory leaks!
> Dumping objects ->
> {24781} normal block at 0x029BCFF8, 28 bytes long.
>  Data: <class CryptoPP::> 63 6C 61 73 73 20 43 72 79 70 74 6F 50 50 3A 3A 
> {24780} normal block at 0x029BCFB0, 8 bytes long.
>  Data: <        > F8 CF 9B 02 00 00 00 00 
> Object dump complete.
> ```

The code you used looks a tad bit unusual, but I believe its well formed.

I believe what you are seeing is Microsoft's decades old bug [typeinfo.name() memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40034232). Its been around since the VC 5.0 or VC 6.0 days.

---

> ```
> CryptoPP::StringSink* pSS = new CryptoPP::StringSink( cipher );
> CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter* pEF = new CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter( rng, e, pSS);
>
> CryptoPP::StringSource ss1( plain, true, pEF);
> ```

Here's what a pipeline often looks like:

```
CryptoPP::StringSource ss( plain, true,
    new CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter( rng, e,
        new CryptoPP::StringSink( cipher )));
```

Everything that follows the code above is a red herring. You went down a rabbit hole because Microsoft won't fix their bugs.

---

> OK, so I did the most obvious thing and added these:
>
> ```
> delete pEF;
> delete pSS;
> ```
>
> but it caused an unhandled exception

Yeah, that was not right. From the [Readme.txt](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/Readme.txt):

> *** Important Usage Notes ***
>
> 1. If a constructor for A takes a pointer to an object B (except primitive types such as int and char), then A owns B and will delete B
>      at A's destruction.  If a constructor for A takes a reference to an
>      object B, then the caller retains ownership of B and should not
>      destroy it until A no longer needs it.
> 2. Crypto++ is thread safe at the class level. This means you can use Crypto++ safely in a multithreaded application, but you must provide
>      synchronization when multiple threads access a common Crypto++ object.

`pEF` and `pSS` were pointers, and they were owned by someone else. They got deleted twice, which caused the exception.

---

> Memory leak in Crypto++ RSAES class ...

If you run the `cryptest.exe` program, then you will see 60 or 80 leaks reported. I've tried to find a solution to that bug for about 10 or 15 years. Most recently was [How to remediate Microsoft typeinfo.name() memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40034232) on Stack Overflow.

***EDIT*** also see [Windows Debug build memory leaks cleared](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/32OQVPdflZk) on the user list and [Commit 301437e693fe8bff](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/301437e693fe8bff). The library moved to static initialization from dynamic initialization to avoid problems on Microsoft platforms. The static initializer list is accessed with `inti_seg` on Windows; and `constructor` and `init_priority` attributes with GCC.

Its a "best effort" to use static initialization, if available. Otherwise, things fall back to dynamic initialization. Here, "static initialization" means getting the library into the CRT static initialization list that runs constructor functions and calls global object ctors (and not a vanilla C++ static object).

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging it. And yes, I saw in other sources that people were blaming Microsoft compiler. But how come if I downgrade from `CryptoPP` v.5.6.5 to v.5.6.2 the memory leak goes away?

Comment: @c00000fd - I'm not sure. A lot changed between 5.6.2 and 5.6.5. We also have not seen your full program. But I'm fairly certain the symptoms you show are the Microsoft bug. First, allocation ***`N`*** dumps the internal (runtime) identifier `class CryptoPP::`. Second, its followed immediately at ***`N+1`*** by a data dump. Note: the internal scheme for tracking classes and names changed at VS2015. They are no longer sequential during the memory dump.

Comment: How about we go the easy route to confirm your theory. Can you post a simple example to demonstrate the typeinfo.name() leak that I can compile in VS2008? Something of just two-three lines of code.

Comment: @jww *"Everything that follows the code above is a red herring. You went down a rabbit hole because Microsoft won't fix their bugs."* Please consider the poor people, who don't have english as their native language. I went through quite a lot of duckduckgoing until I understood what you meant by that.